# woocommerce Product shortcode create

Tags: shortcode, woocommerce-offtopic

i am very new wooCommerce and WordPress. programming knowledge not strong yet. but for my project i need to do something. now i want to create custom short code for woocommerce product.

i want to show product by id or sku. woocommerce built-in shortcodes have and it is working fine which is https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/ but example `[product id="99"]` but if use this shortcodes then it come with add to cart price etc information. mean template take for product. but i want to show only thumbnail picture and name and link. how can i do that ? can do anything in function.php for this. or create separate shortcodes for this.

would you guys help me out . how can i do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello Here is the Shortcode you can use this it will give you title link and image of product.
Put this code in functions.php file of your theme.

```
add_shortcode('product_data','custom_product_function');
function custom_product_function($atts)
{
    $post_id = $atts['id'];
    $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $link = get_the_permalink($post_id);
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
    $data ='<div><a href="'.$link.'"><p>'.$title.'</p></a>'.
    $image.'</div>';
    return $data;
}
```

And then add the shortcode in your page or post with product id

[product_data id=1958]